# Модуляция, модуль, модальность — что общего между этими словами?

Tags: лексика, семантика, недопустимая-метка

**Модуль** — математическое понятие и унифицированный функциональный узел в технике, **модуляция**  — музыкальный термин, модальные слова — в  лингвистике.

Что между ними общего? Это исторически **однокоренные** слова? Но почему они используются в **разных** областях науки и техники, что их **связывает**?